# Difference between health, wellness, and fitness color palettes?

Tags: color-theory

If I google "color palette health", I get something different than if I google  "color palette wellness".  And "color palette  fitness" gives even different results.  I was wondering how you would explain the reasons for differences in terms of emotions? Thanks.

Health: [image]

Welness: [image]

Fitness: [image]

Comment: Except for the word natural being associated with a greenish hue, none of these colour palettes and their word associations make any sense to me.  Colour choice is subjective.  These are just colours someone likes, and has put a word beside.

Answer (score 3):

Color palettes are 100%, without fail, merely someone's **opinion**. Nothing more.

*Your* opinion of what colors to use is *just as **valid*** as *any* search results you may find.

There's *no such thing* as a set color palette based upon a general industry or area of operation. There may be commonalities in an industry because, like you, someone searched for a palette and used what was presented to them. Or they looked at other businesses in the same industry and just gleaned a palette from competitors. But no one *has* to do that. You can just as easily determined your own palette.

Regarding the idea that some colors elicit specific **emotions** - it's largely the same - all *opinion*. Each viewer is *unique* and it's essentially *impossible* to emphatically state what emotion *any* color may elicit. I may find a color calming while you find it disorienting. There may be some broad, general common thoughts such as pastels are more calming. Or darker colors can be more ominous and foreboding. But again, these are pretty much *opinion*. There's no rule stating a pastel color can't be used in a foreboding manner or a dark color in an exciting and happy manner.

Basically, there are *no rules* regarding the *personal perception* of a color palette and anything one finds are all merely *suggestions*. There are *many* web sites that will list things like blue is safe, purple means regal, red is alarming, etc., but *none* of that is set in stone. Such lists are just someone's *personal opinion* that has been infinitely replicated across web sites. Green can be used in a regal manner just as much as purple. Red can be used to promote safety, etc.

---

The difference between those three palettes is someone, somewhere, chose those colors, that's all. You would need to ask then *why* they feel those colors fit a particular industry.

I mean....

Banking:

[image]

Hedge Fund:

[image]

Daycare:

[image]

Labeling a palette for some industry doesn't make it a "rule" or even "guide" by any means.

Comment: That would be the reason both police stations & hospitals used to be painted in slightly nauseating pale green, or artificial leg pink.

Comment: @Tetsujin, which country is that?

Comment: @Wolff - UK, they were popular colours back in the 60s & 70s. It seemed all institutions used the same three colours, there was an insipid blue too. Then in the 80s they all discovered white paint & they've not been the same since;)

Comment: I would like to push back against this answer.  I agree there is a great  deal of subjectivity in color palette choice.  But there is also consistency.  If you google 
"wellness color palette", you will see quite a bit of consistency.  Yes, there are exceptions to the rule.   But most of the results seem to have a lot in common.  Should I post more of these results in my question?

Comment: There's commonality specifically **because** people search for a palette rather than building one. Basically, there are more people which do exactly what you are doing -- ask the internet to pick colors -- rather than determining their own palette. So, those users get the same results and then use that palette (with or without some slight modification). This creates a poole of similar, if not identical, palettes. The older the internet becomes, the more commonality you'll find.

Comment: It is, essentially, nothing more than a cycle that feeds itself. I won't disagree that if you search you find a lot of common palettes. However, that does *not* mean you need to feed the cycle and follow what everyone else is using. After all, any project is not going to stand out if it merely uses the same color palette as everyone else who searched the internet is using.